# Did anyone used Cadence emanager desktop version and moved to Xcelium simulator which doesn't include its license?

Tags: verification, regression-testing, cadence

My team relied on emanager desktop version for regression running, coverage merge and reports until now. When we used incisive simulator, the license included basic usage of emanager (desktop version) that helped us with these features. But now when we moved to Xcelium, emanager is no longer supported, and only vmanager exists. However, this requires a different license, something my boss is not so eager to pay for. I was wondering if anyone here experienced the same problem and how did you deal with it?

We already evaluated the vManager and it suits our needs perfectly, also the move from emanager to vManager was seamless. Right now we're considering writing our own scripts for running regressions and generating reports, but this seems a monumental task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer for you but I think I can shed (a little) light on the license situation:

(Cadence feature numbers in brackets.)

If you were using emanager under Incisive that implies that you had licenses for Incisive Enterprise Simulator - XL (29651) and the IES-XL Advanced Option (29851). When you moved to Xcelium did you move to Xcelium Single Core (X300) or Xcelium Limited Single Core (X100)?

X300 licenses are supposed to contain all the features of 29851 and hence have emanager available as part of the simulator license.

We are just starting the switch over from Incisive and this is what I have been told by Cadence.

Comment: I checked now, we have x309 (xcelium legacy single core). It does include emanager license since it includes incisive licenses to be able to run incisive on old projects (that might be not fitted for the new simulator). However, if you run xcelium simulations on emanager, it won't be able to merge and view the coverage results since the coverage db version of xcelium is incompatible with emanager.